# Protecting resources such as images in a servlet

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

Let's say that you have an image I that you only want users who have logged into your website to be able to see. What is the best way to protect I from non-logged in users. One possible way is to have a page where you pass the image name via get or post parameters, and it would return the image by reading the image from disk and writing back in the response based on if the user was logged in the session. Is/Are there better ways to achieve security of resources more efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple easy ways you could to this with [servlet filters](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) or just plain servlet that servers your resource.

Personally I would check if the principal have been set is so then you know the user is authenitcated

```
    Principal principal = request.getUserPrincipal();
    if (principal == null) {
        return null;
    }
```

If there is no principal you know the user is not authenticated, you could return 403 status, blank image or whatever you like.

Answer (score 2):

use your session. when the user is logged in, you load the image to your page.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to protect the urls of the image files, set some rules about their access in your code. I think a better alternative is using some security framework. There are some security platforms like [Spring Security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/) provide very comprehensive access rules based on user authentication status, url-role combination, and acl, etc..